# Fermi integral; chemical potential vs temperature

Tags: physics, fermi-dirac-integral

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\exp{(z - \tilde{\mu}) + 1}}dz = \dfrac{2}{3} \tilde{T}^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

I try to find chemical potential as the function of temperature

Comment: I advise you not to write hello in the tittle because posts must be clear & concise. (:

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt z}{\exp{(z - \tilde{\mu}) + 1}}\,dz =\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt z}{1+k\exp{(z ) }}dz $$ where $k=e^{- \tilde{\mu}}$.

This leads to
$$I=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\,  \text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-\frac{1}{k}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \, \text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-e^{\tilde{\mu}) }\right)$$ where appears the polylogarithm function.

Have a look [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0911/0911.4452.pdf).

For solving the equation, you will need some numerical method such as Newton. I should work fine since the rhs is a quite smooth function. From a practical point of view, I should try to find $\tilde{\mu}$ looking for the zero of
$$f(\tilde{\mu})=\log \left(-\frac{ \sqrt{\pi }}{2}\, \text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-e^{\tilde{\mu}   }\right)\right)-\log\left( \dfrac{2}{3} \tilde{T}^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)$$ using
$$f'(\tilde{\mu})=\frac{\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-e^{\tilde{\mu}
   }\right)}{\text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-e^{\tilde{\mu} }\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrewSemyonov. I added a few lines to my answer. If you provide a range of $\tilde{T}$, I could probably provide at least resonable approximations for $\tilde{\mu}$

Comment: Well, can I use inverse quadratic interpolation method to solve it?

Comment: @AndrewSemyonov : Any root-finding method will do the job. Just  out of curiosity, give me the range of $\tilde{T}$. I enjoy function approximations.

Comment: The  range of $\tilde{T}$ is somewhere about (0, 5), the left border must be exactly $0$

Comment: And it's just a part of my equation, I need to find out how Fermi gas depends on its temperature, so I'm trying to figure out $\mu(T)$

Comment: i tried to take $\tilde{T}(\tilde{\mu})$:
$$\tilde{T}(\tilde{\mu}) = \left( - \dfrac{3}{4} \sqrt{\pi} Li_{3/2} (-\exp{(\tilde{\mu})})\right)^{-2/3}$$
And find $ \tilde{\mu(T)}$, but i can't

Comment: @AndrewSemyonov. If you plot $\log(T(\mu))$ as a function of $\mu$ you almost have a straitgh line.